# C#, Webapplication. Testing Excel file generation

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing

In many C# .NET WebApplications the user needs to download data as Excel File.

To create/manage Excel spreadsheets I use: [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/).

To open Excel files, I use and recommend: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/).

In a MVC webapplication I make the Excel file available for download:

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcell()
{
    byte[] report = _codeManager.CreateExcel();
    return BinaryResponseReport(report);
}

private ActionResult BinaryResponseReport(byte[] report)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FooBar.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(report);
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But when testing the `_codeManager.CreateExcel()` functionality I do not want to run through all the various steps of the web application over and over again to get to the download Excell functionality.

So within my UnitTest project of the solution. I add a TestMethod:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestExcellGeneration()
{       
    byte[] report = _codeManager.CreateExcel();
    OpenExcelFromTempFile(excelFileBytes);
}

private void OpenExcelFromTempFile(byte[] data)
{
    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, data);
    Application excelApplication = new Application();
    _Workbook excelWorkbook;
    excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(tempPath);
    excelApplication.Visible = true; 
}
```

Running this unit test will write the excell to a TempFile.

**My Question:**
Should I add such 'Unit-Tests' to my solution?
Is there an alternative or better way to test this functionality?

As I am not actually testing functionality in a
`Arrange`  `Act` `Assert` way.

Comment: why do you have the `Application` thing in the bit? in the coded test you would actually parse the excel doc (e.g. `OpenXmlSdk` or similar) and Assert that the correct data is there.
In the e2e test you would use something like Selenium to actually click buttons in the browser.

What you wrote currently doesn't seem to have any practical value (or am i missing something?)

Comment: @zaitsman: The focus here is on testing the actual excel sheet as an outcome after you collected the necessary data, not so much on the buildup of the underlying data.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by '`testing the actual excel sheet as an outcome`'

Comment: @zaitsman did you ever create an excel file from code? It is hard to visualize the actual outcome from just code. You want to see the actual outcome to be sure that your code is good.